# How to derive a simultaneous confidence band for an estimated function?

Tags: confidence-interval, cox-model, splines

I'm approximating the functional form of the Cox model by *B*-splines basis functions. For simplicity, assume there's only one covariate $x$, so my model takes the form

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda(t|x)&=&\lambda_0(t)\cdot\exp(\eta(x))\\
&\approx& \lambda_0(t)\cdot\exp(\sum_{j}\gamma_jB_j(x))\\
\end{eqnarray*}

The coefficients $\gamma$’s are estimated by the usual partial likelihood method and their asymptotic properties are also derived. Next, I intend to construct a simultaneous confidence band for this estimated function, $\hat{\eta}(x)$. Bootstrapping may be one way, so my question is whether it is possible to derive an exact or a conservative band by the normality property of the coefficients as well.

Any suggestion or reference is appreciated.